# Calculating percentage of count and adding it to the count in MySQL table with the query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.0

I have following basic MySQL query and I my aim is to artificially inflate the amount of today's orders by 75%.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this without using `COUNT` twice?

```
SELECT COUNT(order_id) + (COUNT(order_id) * 0.75) AS total
FROM orders
WHERE order_date BETWEEN BETWEEN CURDATE() + ' 00:00:00' AND NOW()
```

**EDIT: I spotted an issue with my query (using `+` for concatenation when I should have used `CONCAT`)**

Comment: `CURDATE() + ' 00:00:00'` is not what you want -- "+" is not "CONCAT".  Anyway `CURDATE()` performs equally well without the time.

Comment: 5.0 is already ten years old - did you ever think about upgrading to something current?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For general case use your original query as derived table:

```
SELECT cnt + (cnt * 0.75) AS total
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(order_id) AS cnt
    FROM orders
    WHERE order_date BETWEEN CURDATE() + ' 00:00:00' AND NOW()
) AS tmp
```

But in your case it is much simpler:

```
SELECT (COUNT(order_id) * 1.75) AS total
FROM orders
WHERE order_date BETWEEN CURDATE() + ' 00:00:00' AND NOW()
```